# Node offline API

Tags: node.js, api, express

Is it possible to create an API (with node.js) than handles get request from a mobile app?

I've read about service workers but I don't know if it's possible to use one to make an api to handle get request even when the client has no internet connection.

I'm trying to build an application which returns information about pediatric medicines even if the client is offline.

Comment: if the "Api" is only reachable through HTTP... if the user is offline, it will never reach the API... so there's nothing in the API you can do... What you can do is, on the mobile side, to have the whole data cached and when you have a timeout to reach the API, load data from the cache...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to create an API (with node.js) than handles get request from a mobile app?

Yes, it is possible. `Node.js` is a great choice to build your API and it has many advantages. API for a mobile app is not gonna be different from API for a regular website - same handlers, same `get` and `post` verbs.

> I've read about service workers but I don't know if it's possible to use one to make an api work offline

I'm not 100% sure what do you mean by `api work offline`. API is just a piece of code which is executed on a server and this piece of code (usually) simply waits for a request to come so API can handle it. Some APIs can push data to clients, for example, thru WebSockets.

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/introduction-to-service-worker) `service worker` is:

> It's essentially a JavaScript file that runs separately from the main
>   browser thread, intercepting network requests, caching or retrieving
>   resources from the cache, and delivering push messages.

So, you can use `service worker` to make your [PWA](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps) website/app look alive even if you backend is down/unavailable.

The schema is more like this:

[image: service worker schema]

## Update

So, `service worker` lives on the client side and intercepts calls from a web page. Imagine that you simply make an AJAX request to your API from a page. Usually it goes directly to API, but `service worker` has an ability to intercept it and check if app is online or not. If yes, `service worker` gets information from API and stores it to `Cache`. If not `service worker` gets information from the `Cache` so for a web page it looks the same - page just got data.

[image: service worker lifecycle]

Here is a [good example](https://github.com/ireade/boilerplate-service-worker) and a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ksXwaWHCW6k) and I'll put some code here too, just in case.

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Boilerplate Service Worker</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Boilerplate Service Worker</h1>

        <p>Below is an image of Earth from NASA</p>

        <p><img src="" alt="Image of Earth from Nasa" class="targetImage"></p>      
    </div>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {

  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register('./service-worker.js', { scope: './' })
    .then(function(registration) {
      console.log("Service Worker Registered");
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log("Service Worker Failed to Register", err);
    })
}

// Function to perform HTTP request
var get = function(url) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                var result = xhr.responseText
                result = JSON.parse(result);
                resolve(result);
            } else {
                reject(xhr);
            }
        }
    };

    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.send();

  }); 
};

get('https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/earth/imagery?api_key=fWfSMcDzyHfMuH3BW6jiIUBYaj3hKRyKBRTBqgEQ')
  .then(function(response) {
    // There is an issue with the image being pulled from the API, so using a different one instead
    document.getElementsByClassName('targetImage')[0].src = "https://api.nasa.gov/images/earth.png";

  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log("Error", err);
  })
```

**service-worker.js**

```
// Set a name for the current cache
var cacheName = 'v1'; 

// Default files to always cache
var cacheFiles = [
    './',
    './index.html',
    './js/app.js',
    './css/reset.css',
    './css/style.css',
    'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,700,400italic,700italic'
]


self.addEventListener('install', function(e) {
    console.log('[ServiceWorker] Installed');

    // e.waitUntil Delays the event until the Promise is resolved
    e.waitUntil(

        // Open the cache
        caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {

            // Add all the default files to the cache
            console.log('[ServiceWorker] Caching cacheFiles');
            return cache.addAll(cacheFiles);
        })
    ); // end e.waitUntil
});


self.addEventListener('activate', function(e) {
    console.log('[ServiceWorker] Activated');

    e.waitUntil(

        // Get all the cache keys (cacheName)
        caches.keys().then(function(cacheNames) {
            return Promise.all(cacheNames.map(function(thisCacheName) {

                // If a cached item is saved under a previous cacheName
                if (thisCacheName !== cacheName) {

                    // Delete that cached file
                    console.log('[ServiceWorker] Removing Cached Files from Cache - ', thisCacheName);
                    return caches.delete(thisCacheName);
                }
            }));
        })
    ); // end e.waitUntil

});


self.addEventListener('fetch', function(e) {
    console.log('[ServiceWorker] Fetch', e.request.url);

    // e.respondWidth Responds to the fetch event
    e.respondWith(

        // Check in cache for the request being made
        caches.match(e.request)


            .then(function(response) {

                // If the request is in the cache
                if ( response ) {
                    console.log("[ServiceWorker] Found in Cache", e.request.url, response);
                    // Return the cached version
                    return response;
                }

                // If the request is NOT in the cache, fetch and cache

                var requestClone = e.request.clone();
                return fetch(requestClone)
                    .then(function(response) {

                        if ( !response ) {
                            console.log("[ServiceWorker] No response from fetch ")
                            return response;
                        }

                        var responseClone = response.clone();

                        //  Open the cache
                        caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {

                            // Put the fetched response in the cache
                            cache.put(e.request, responseClone);
                            console.log('[ServiceWorker] New Data Cached', e.request.url);

                            // Return the response
                            return response;

                        }); // end caches.open

                    })
                    .catch(function(err) {
                        console.log('[ServiceWorker] Error Fetching & Caching New Data', err);
                    });


            }) // end caches.match(e.request)
    ); // end e.respondWith
});
```

and you can find a [style.css here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ireade/boilerplate-service-worker/gh-pages/src/css/style.css) and [reset.css here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ireade/boilerplate-service-worker/gh-pages/src/css/reset.css). Those are not really important for this question, but just in case.

This example shows how to cache files, register `service worker` and subscribe for `install`, `activate` and `fetch` events.

I hope it helps

Comment: what i mean with **'offline'** is to be able to handle get request when the client has no internet

Comment: @CarlosPadron I hope I answered your question - yes, with `service worker` you can do that. Backend API could be build using NodeJs or any other language.

Comment: thank you very much. Can you explain how can I implement a sw? In which part of the API should I implement the sw? I'm pretty new on api development.

Comment: @CarlosPadron sure, but please don't forget to 'accept' an answer - I updated it. You don't need to change API - `service worker` lives **on the client side** i.e. page

Comment: Thanks for your help Pavel